# What is the meaning and reading of this kanji?

Tags: meaning, kanji, readings

I’m reading とんがり帽子のアトリエ and I encountered a kanji which defies all my attempts to look up, whether by radicals or drawing. I’ve attached a picture, the kanji in question is at the top of the third line. I assume it means something like “require” since the sentence seems to mean “As for handling, care is required,” but I’d like to know the exact meaning and reading. Please also include the kanji in the answer so I can copy it. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a weird graphic variant of 求める, so your guess as to the meaning is right.